# CUDA Thrust return type

Tags: c++, c, cuda, thrust

I am currently trying to use the Thrust library and I am having issues with the return types.

```
  device_vector<int> input(5);

  input[0] = 0;
  input[1] = 2;
  input[2] = 5;
  input[3] = 7;
  input[4] = 8;

  pair<int*, int*> result= minmax_element(input.begin(), input.end());
```

gives the error:

```
 error : no suitable conversion function from "const thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>>" to "int *" exists
```

Could someone please explain to me how work out what the return type should be?

according to the [documentation](http://thrust.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.0/doc/html/group__extrema.html) the return type is

```
thrust::pair<ForwardIterator,ForwardIterator>
```

However this not not working for me, could someone please explain!

Thanks!

Comment: Well, why don't you declare `result` as the correct type then? There's no implicit conversion from a `vector<T>::iterator` to a `T*` even in the C++ standard library.

Comment: Explain what exactly? An iterator to `int` is similar, but not quite the same as a pointer to `int`, I guess this is clear to you?

Comment: No. An iterator is an iterator, an `int*` is an `int*`. Nobody says that the two are related, so don't walk around pretending they are. (Don't second-guess *implementation details*. They're none of your business.)

Comment: @Kerrek: assuming you were referring to my comment, I changed "almost the same" to similar: you're right, that's a better way to say it. They definitely _are_ similar, in that they behave the same with respect to `operator*`.

Comment: @leftroundabout: Oh, I'm very sorry, I thought the comment was by the OP :-) Of course you're right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When naming a template parameter, `ForwardIterator` does not name any particular type.  For our purposes, we can think of it as a placeholder for the type of iterator given to `thrust::minmax_element`:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator>
  thrust::pair<ForwardIterator,ForwardIterator> minmax_element(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last);
```

So `minmax_element` returns a `pair` of whatever type of iterator is given to it as arguments.

In your case, `minmax_element` returns a `pair` of `device_vector<int>::iterator`s. You can make your code compile by making `result` the appropriate `pair`:

```
device_vector<int> input(5);

input[0] = 0;
input[1] = 2;
input[2] = 5;
input[3] = 7;
input[4] = 8;

// we can use a typedef for brevity
typedef pair<device_vector<int>::iterator, device_vector<int>::iterator> result_type;

result_type result = minmax_element(input.begin(), input.end());

// check the results
assert(0 == *result.first);
assert(8 == *result.second);
```